# The icon doesn't show in production nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The meta link icon doesn't show in production nextjs but shows in localhost.

**code**:

```
const Home: NextPage<HomeProps> = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>The Stobook</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="The Stobook is an open library where you can read any book for free. It features a customizable auto function that suggests depending on user preferences."
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/book.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.index__container}>
        //SomeCode
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`book.ico` is in public folder.
It works in localhost, but doesn't show after I deployed it into vercel.
I also tried import the book.ico and href={icon.src} but thats causes error.

Comment: What happens if you directly access `book.ico` on a browser - i.e `<yourvercelapp>/book.ico`

Comment: @Ramakay It shows the icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue could be related to two reasons

1. If you have a `basePath` defined in your `next.config.js` then your path becomes - `/basepath/book.ico`
2. NextJS vercel hosting issue  - Try adding it to a `images` folder inside root - i.e

i.e

`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/book.ico" />`

Comment: 1. No basePath in next.config.js
2. Other images inside public folder is show in other parts of the app.

But yeah thanks, adding `type="image/x-icon"` worked